# ROS Answers SE migration: Rviz crashes

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed the transport hint in Image tab at rviz from 'raw' to 'tf' and it crashed. Now I am facing this error while opening it. Re-installation and recompilation did not work. How to pass through it? Thanks

```
[ERROR] [1338181335.401547975]: Caught exception while loading: Unable to load plugin for transport 'tf', error string:
According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class image_transport/tf_sub with base class type image_transport::SubscriberPlugin does not exist. Declared types are  image_transport/compressed_sub image_transport/raw_sub image_transport/theora_sub
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35004/rviz-crashes/) by [Reza Ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1696/reza-ch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz saves it's config in the '.rviz' subfolder of your home folder. The easiest option is to just delete the entire 'rviz' folder (it will be re-created on the next rviz startup). You could also look into the config files and try to edit them as to fix the error.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1